# How to Create a table with data from array output in Python

Tags: python, dataframe

I printed out composed array and saved to text file, it like:

```
({
    ngram_a67e6f3205f0-n: 1,
    logreg_c120232d9faa-regParam: 0.01,
    cntVec_9c0e7831261d-vocabSize: 10000
},0.8580469779197205)
({
    ngram_a67e6f3205f0-n: 2,
    logreg_c120232d9faa-regParam: 0.01,
    cntVec_9c0e7831261d-vocabSize: 10000
},0.8880895806519427)
({
    ngram_a67e6f3205f0-n: 3,
    logreg_c120232d9faa-regParam: 0.01,
    cntVec_9c0e7831261d-vocabSize: 10000
},0.8656452460818544)
```

I hope extract data to produce python Dataframe, it like:

```
1, 10000, 0.8580469779197205
2, 10000, 0.8880895806519427
```

Comment: You saved it to a txt file exactly like that?

Comment: Yes, the content of files is result of cross validation. I print out it, then copied it to files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice is to change the input format of your file, if possible. It would greatly simplify your life. 
If this is not possible, the following code solves your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

pattern_tuples = '(?<=\()[^\)]*'
pattern_numbers = '[ ,](?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?'
col_name = ['ngram', 'logreg', 'vocabSize', 'score']

with open('test.txt','r') as f:
    matchs = re.findall(pattern_tuples, f.read())
    arr_data = [[float(val.replace(',','')) for val in re.findall(pattern_numbers, match)] for match in matchs]
    df = pd.DataFrame(arr_data, columns=col_name).astype({'ngram':'int', 'vocabSize': 'int'})
```

and gives:

```
   ngram  logreg  vocabSize     score
0      1    0.01      10000  0.858047
1      2    0.01      10000  0.888090
2      3    0.01      10000  0.865645
```

---

### Brief explanation

1. Read the file
2. Using [re.findall](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents) and the regex `pattern_tuples` finds all the tuples in the file
3. For each tuple, using the regex `pattern_numbers` you will find the 4 numerical values ​​that interest you. In this way you will get a list of lists containing your data
4. Enter the results in a pandas dataframe

---

### Extra

Here's how you could save your CV results in *json format*, so you can manage them more easily:

1. Create an `cv_results` array to keep the CV results
2. For each loop of CVs you will get a tuple `t` with the results, which you will have to transform into a dictionary and hang in the array `cv_results`
3. At the end of the CV loops, save the results in json format

.

```
cv_results = []

for _ in range_cv: # Loop CV
    # ... Calculate results of CV in t
    t = ({'ngram_a67e6f3205f0-n': 1,
       'logreg_c120232d9faa-regParam': 0.01,
       'cntVec_9c0e7831261d-vocabSize': 10000},
      0.8580469779197205) # FAKE DATA for this example

    # append results like a dict
    cv_results.append({'res':t[0], 'score':t[1]})

# Store results in json format
with open('cv_results.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(cv_results, outfile, indent=4)
```

Now you can read the json file and you can access all the fields like a normal python dictionary:

```
with open('cv_results.json') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)

data[0]['score']
# output: 0.8580469779197205
```

Comment: Yes. it is powerful!

Comment: if you want to switch to using a json, I updated the answer giving you some advice. Good luck :) @IvanLee

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
import pandas as pd
With open(file.txt) as file:
    df = pd.DataFrame([i for i in eval(file.readline())])
```

Eval takes a string and converts it to the literal python representation which is pretty nifty. That would convert each parenthetical to a single item iterator which is then stored into a list. Pd dataframe class can take a list of dictionaries with identical keys and create a dataframe

Comment: Have you tried this on the given text? I don't think it works